# How can I add markers on navigationlauncher of mapbox?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using mapbox for map navigation.. is it possible to add markers on navigation view on mapbox like the waze app? when you start navigating markers are still shown on navigation

Answer (score 0):

The `NavigationView` allows access to the `MapboxMap` via `NavigationView#retrieveMap()`.  Once initialized, you should be able to use this to create your own `SymbolManager` using the annotation plugin.  You can then use the plugin as your normally would to add / remove custom markers to the map.

Comment: do i need to create a new class of NavigationView?

Comment: Are you currently using `NavigationLauncher`?  Unfortunately, `NavigationLauncher` will not support this use-case and you need to use `NavigationView` within your own `Activity` or `Fragment`.  Our documentation examples should help explain this as well https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/examples/embedded-navigation/

Comment: Hi @DanNesfeder I am using NavigationView but i didn't get any method to get MapBox Map. I am using :mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.2